# Python read file into array, wrong value

Tags: python, arrays, io

following is the code, I am trying to read a file line by line and write the value into an array accordingly, however, when I print *sensing*, it does contain a lot of elements, but their value is the last *trimmed*.

```
sensing = []
with open("data.txt") as data:
    for line in data:        
        strline = line.strip()
        if(strline[1] =='[' ):
            trimmed[0] = int(strline[2:5])
            trimmed[1] = int(strline[7:10])
        else:
            trimmed[0] = int(strline[1:4])
            trimmed[1] = int(strline[6:9])
        **sensing.append(trimmed)**
```

data.txt: [592, 180],[583, 189],[576, 197],[569, 205],[560, 214],[551, 225],

sensing: [[551, 225], [551, 225], [551, 225], [551, 225], [551, 225], [551, 225]]

what I want: sensing: [[592, 180],[583, 189],[576, 197],[569, 205],[560, 214],[551, 225]]

Comment: Where do you first define the "trimmed" variable? It's not in that code.

Comment: Lists are mutable so if you define trimmed outside of this loop, and reuse it, you will get the result you've outlined... move trimmed inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is almost certainly with references. Lists (and most objects) in Python are held in reference variables. Each list in sensing is pointing to a list in memory that you call trimmed. When you change trimmed, all the sub-lists in sensing get updated because they're all pointing to that one list.

You either need to re-define trimmed each iteration through the loop (with `trimmed = [None, None]`) or you could just append directly to the sensing lists with something like `sensing[-1].append(element)` and `sensing.append([])` to add a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a line of input is: [592, 180],[583, 189],[576, 197],[569, 205],[560, 214],[551, 225]

```
sensing = []
with open("data.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        sendsing = [map(int, i.split(", ")) for i in line.strip()[1:-1].split("],[")]
```